# non-blocking datagram socket, read and write

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp

for non-blocking datagram socket, like UDP,
when I call write()/send() on the socket, if the bytes to write is 1000 bytes,
but in case that I write too often, maybe the write(send) buffer is not enough,
for example, only 200 bytes buffer available.
then I will write 200 bytes or 0 bytes? is the returned error is EAGAIN nor any other error?

for read()/recv() on a socket, each call of them will just return extacly 1 datagram, is it or not?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> if the bytes to write is 1000 bytes, but in case that I write too often, maybe the write(send) buffer is not enough, for example, only 200 bytes buffer available. then I will write 200 bytes or 0 bytes?

Zero.

> is the returned error is EAGAIN nor any other error?

`EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` depending on your platform.

> How about read()?

It will return either a complete UDP datagram or zero.

This is a primary property of UDP.

Comment: If you are referring to recvfrom(), it returns the number of bytes received if there was no error. Why don't you check your documentation?

Comment: for non-blocking datagram socket, recvfrom() returns the number of bytes? I think it returns the whole packet,isn't it?  there is no specific information in this regard in the documentation.

Comment: Here is copy/paste from the MSDN: If no error occurs, recvfrom returns the number of bytes received. If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.

Comment: @user1764961 this is obviously for tcp connection, not datagram socket.

Comment: read the first sentence here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user1764961 it seems to me that what EJP said is different from the documentation.

Comment: I guess this could be different on different platforms. You didn't tell what is your platform.